# Maven Assembly: Unabe to run fat jar

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have created a fat jar using maven assembly plugin. Following is the pom file with some sensitive details hidden:-

```
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>labs.rule</groupId>
<artifactId>labs-engine</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Labs Engine</name>
<description>Rule engines @ XXX</description>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <!-- get all project dependencies -->
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <!-- MainClass in mainfest make a executable jar -->
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                        <mainClass>main.java.labs.RuleEngine</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>make-assembly</id>
                    <!-- bind to the packaging phase -->
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<!-- distributionManagement entry is for enabling upload to bidstalk maven
                    repos -->
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>My-maven-repository</id>
        <name>My-maven-repository-releases</name>
        <url>http://X.Y.Z.W:ZZZ/artifactory/simple/My</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>sonatype-forge</id>
        <url>https://repository.sonatype.org/content/groups/forge/</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>My-maven-repository</id>
        <name>My-maven-repository-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://X.Y.Z.W:ZZZ/artifactory/simple/My</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-cli</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-cli</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
        <version>3.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-configuration</artifactId>
        <version>1.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aerospike</groupId>
        <artifactId>aerospike-client</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazonaws</groupId>
        <artifactId>aws-java-sdk-redshift</artifactId>
        <version>1.11.31</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.applift.commonslib</groupId>
        <artifactId>alertslib</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.amazon</groupId>
        <artifactId>redshift.jdbc41</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.13.1013</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.34</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

I am able to run the code from eclipse, but I need to deploy a fat jar, which I have created in maven at package phase.

However when I tried to run the jar using:-

```
java -jar target/labs-engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

It gave following exception:-

```
Exception in thread "main" java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://X-Y-Z.com:3306/labs_staging
```

Now what is it I am missing while creating fat jar? Note that:-

1. mysql-connector is being included in pom.xml.
2. I am able to run in Eclipse
3. com.mysql.jdbc package is present in the created fat jar.

**EDIT:**
Output of `mvn clean install`

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Labs Engine 0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ labs-engine ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/target
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ labs-engine ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/src/main/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:compile (default-compile) @ labs-engine ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[WARNING] File encoding has not been set, using platform encoding UTF-8, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] Compiling 8 source files to /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/target/classes
[WARNING] /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/src/main/java/labs/RuleEngineAerospikeConnection.java: /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/src/main/java/labs/RuleEngineAerospikeConnection.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
[WARNING] /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/src/main/java/labs/RuleEngineAerospikeConnection.java: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ labs-engine ---
[WARNING] Using platform encoding (UTF-8 actually) to copy filtered resources, i.e. build is platform dependent!
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/src/test/resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ labs-engine ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ labs-engine ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-jar-plugin:2.4:jar (default-jar) @ labs-engine ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/target/labs-engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-assembly-plugin:2.4.1:single (make-assembly) @ labs-engine ---
[INFO] Building jar: /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/target/labs-engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.4:install (default-install) @ labs-engine ---
[INFO] Installing /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/target/labs-engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar to /Users/mangat/.m2/repository/labs/rule/labs-engine/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/labs-engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
[INFO] Installing /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/pom.xml to /Users/mangat/.m2/repository/labs/rule/labs-engine/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/labs-engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] Installing /Users/mangat/Documents/workspace/labs-rule-engine/target/labs-engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar to /Users/mangat/.m2/repository/labs/rule/labs-engine/0.0.1-SNAPSHOT/labs-engine-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 12.707 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-09-12T20:13:32+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 43M/379M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: You could be missing the configuration file required by the ServiceLocator which finds the appropriate jdbc driver.

Comment: @PeterLawrey I haven't created any configuration file. Do I need one while creating jax executable. I am loading driver by Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: If you load it explicitly you shouldn't also need a service locator configuration file, But I could be wrong. I wasn't sure that when you combine JARs that this file or some other resource in the meta data doesn't get clobbered.

Comment: Try to run it from `target` dir.

Comment: @talex same result!

Comment: @PeterLawrey Any idea how to create the configuration for driver? I will try if it works.

Comment: Remove your `<addClasspath>true</addClasspath>` configuration, you don't need it. Can you 1. run `mvn clean install` and try again and 2. post the full stacktrace?

Comment: In your dependencies do you have file `java.sql.Driver`? If there is multiple occurrences of this file it will be overwritten.

Comment: @Tunaki Please check the edit

Comment: @talex I guess you are right. There is  org.gjt.mm.mysql.Driver present along with com.mysql.jdbc.Driver. How do I know which library is importing this class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try next hotfix.

Add to your project resource `META-INF/services/java.sql.Driver` file with next content:

```
com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver
```

after build make sure that `*-jar-with-dependencies.jar` file (it is plain zip file, rename it to look inside) contains this file with right content.

It is not best solution, but if it helps we can find btter one.

Comment: I did exactly that, but found "com.amazon.redshift.jdbc41.Driver" as content to the file. Now I need both the drivers. I am using redshift too.

Comment: If you need several driver you should rethink about using fat jar.

Comment: Oops, I am stuck. Because I need to deploy on Amazon EC2 the Java application and It needs only a fat jar to execute.

Comment: There is a solution to solve your problem. You need to write proper `assembli.xml`, but i can't help you with this. Didn't do it for long time. you can start here http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/usage.html

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the help @talex. Simply swapping loading mysql driver earlier than redshift dynamically solved the issue. Now I am reading about assembli.xml for the project.